# Is there a standard way to get all elements with a class name WITHIN a certain node?

Tags: java, dom, w3c

I know of `Document.getElementsByClassname(String)` to get all elements of a specific class name in the entire document.

I'm now trying to get those elements within a specific node of the document. In the `org.w3c.dom.Element`, I only find `getElementsByTagname`. Do I really need to iterate over all these elements and read the class name, or is there a better way?

I'm trying to find a solution using Java only (can be with another library).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: no I mean Java. There's a standard DOM library in Java (org.w3c.dom.*), but it doesn't contain this method I'm indicating. I'm wondering where I could find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using JSoup, which contains the method I need.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByClass%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

Despite you are working with `org.w3c.dom.Document` objects, this should work aswell.

I found a solution for this in [Getting specific elements with XPath from an SVG with Batik](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26114760/1588163) that uses the `xalan` library. The only difference is that I ended up using `XPathAPI` instead of `XPathEvaluator` because of `batik` inconsistencies with the `org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator` implementation.

This is the relevant part of the code I wrote:

```
Element searchRoot= document.getRootElement();
NodeList nl = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(searchRoot, ".//*[@class=\"class_name\"]");
```

Answer (score -3):

jQuery is the better way.

This selects all of the nodes with a class of "classNameToFind" in the node with a id of "nodeToSearchName".

$("#nodeToSearchName").find(".classNameToFind")

Comment: what if I only want to use Java?